# Change Links within DIV to use JQuery Load

Tags: jquery, load, attr

I am trying to make a script whereby cetain links use JQuery load instead

This does not work.

```
function inload() {
$('#sausage').load(this.attr('href') + ' #sausage');
return false;
}
```

I think the problem is with my t`his.attr('href')` but I require some advice.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").live("click",function(e){  //.live not .click so the function will also work on the newly loaded content

    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action of clicking the link

    var href = $(this).attr("href"); //grab the links href

    $("body").load(href,callback); //load the contents of the href info the body of the page

});

//added a callback for running after the content has loaded if required
function callback(){
    alert("content loaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$('#sausage').load($(this).attr('href')+'#sausage');
```

or

```
$('#sausage').load(this.href+'#sausage');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get at the `href` you can simply do `this.href` this assumes you are actually using an `<a/>` tag, and `this` is a `Dom Element`

```
function inload() {
  $('#sausage').load(this.href + ' #sausage');
  return false;
}
```

Otherwise use `$(this).attr('href');`